# How to enable Oozie audit log?

Tags: log4j, cloudera, oozie

I want to know, how to enable Oozie audit log using log4j.

I googled and couldn't find any detail info.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following line in the log4j.properties vi Cloudera Manager, and it worked.

```
log4j.logger.oozieaudit=ALL, oozieaudit(before)

log4j.logger.oozieaudit=INFO, oozieaudit(after)
```